# www.website.com/sitecore always redirecting to www.website.com

Tags: admin-pages

From times to times I face this very much weird issue.

All of a sudden I'm **no longer able to access the Sitecore administrator console**.

When I type `/sitecore` I'm always redirected to the home page.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To bypass this annoying redirect, instead of typing `/sitecore` I just type `/sitecore/login` and keep moving.

The last time this happened I decided to **investigate a little bit more the cookies involved** in the issue and realized that by deleting the cookie `sitecore_userticket` the bug stop happening.

[image]

Using those two strategies I can get rid of the weird issue even it doesn't explain why that happened at first place.